# String Comparison in python by ignoring the Mixed Case

Tags: python-3.x

I am actually trying to validate a string which is mixed case. Example:

WeLComE: this is my default string -- `string1`.

I am retrieving same string from some other method which is coming as welcome (lower case) -- `string2`.

When I am comparing both of them and keeping an `if` test for both the strings to match. But as these both are in different case, I am unable to go inside the `if` block. So I am doing

```
if string2 == string1.lower():
```

which is working for me.

But is there any other way which can ignore the case for the strings and compare them. 
Any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is fine. If you are sure that string2 is always in lower case, you can certainly compare with

```
if string2 == string1.lower():
```

Or else go with

```
if string2.lower() == string1.lower():
```

If you **absolutely** need a different approach, go with

```
import re
if re.match("^welcome$", "WeLcOmE", re.I)
```

Comment: Yes.. my string2 is always lower case. as of now I am doing the same as you said. But is there any other way to ignore the case/mixed case

Comment: I don't understand why you absolutely want a different approach. Your example is fine, as I told you. It's probably the easiest and least computing time consuming way of comparing two strings. Also, this question has been asked before many times.

Comment: I am not sure when I get a mixed case word. As of now I can use the above one which serves my work. But I wanted to know if there is any thing else to do that, so that in future my code will not fail to compare with the case of two strings. So I wanted to ignore it always